# google capstone data file import from mac desktop issue

Tags: r, macos, csv, import-csv

I am very new to programming and am working on the Google Data Analytics Certificate. I have looked everywhere for assistance to my issue and nothing has worked. (I have watched videos, searched stack overflow, queried kaggle, etc.)

I am working on the bellabeat capstone project and have been able to download the data files to my mac desktop.

My issue is that I am unable to import these data files into r, which I am running locally on my machine.

Based on the breadcrumb trail of where my files are located, I have been trying to run this code:

```
dailyActivity_merged <- read.csv(~"⁨Macintosh HD⁩/Users/.../googlecapstone_bellabeat_data/Fitabase_Data_20160412to20160512/dailyActivity_merged.csv")
```

I have received this error:

```
Error: bidi formatting not allowed (line 1), use escapes instead (\u2068)
```

Based on the "escapes" reference in the error statement, I have tried to change "/" to this "" and that hasn't worked.

Could someone please point me in the direction for a solution? If there are tutors available somewhere, I would be interested in hearing about that as well.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

RB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need to explicitly define the file location for your project, but I usually don't. I use the following code to import files

```
dailyActivity_merged = read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)
```

do not include anything in the parenthesis. You want to copy this line of code exactly.

Comment: I tried this dailyActivity_merged = read.csv(file.choose(dailyActivity_merged.csv),header = TRUE) got this error Error in file.choose(dailyActivity_merged.csv) : 
  object 'dailyActivity_merged.csv' not found

Comment: I then tried this dailyActivity_merged = read.csv(file.choose(~"⁨Macintosh HD⁩/Users/richbehrens/Desktop/resume2022/googlecapstone_bellabeat_data/Fitabase_Data_20160412to20160512/dailyActivity_merged.csv"),header = TRUE)
Error: bidi formatting not allowed (line 1), use escapes instead (\u2068)

Comment: don't put anything in the parenthesis. this will allow a popup screen to appear where you can manually go through your folders and click the one you want

Comment: literally type this ```dailyActivity_merged = read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)```

Comment: i tried the method you suggested and the popup occurred! thank you so much!

Comment: dailyActivity_merged = read.csv(file.choose(),header = TRUE)
objc[30561]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff8ab713d8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x1104ccf50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Comment: That looks like an Apple specific message. I am not too familiar with Apple, sorry! But on their website it says that it is an Apple problem and harmless. I'm not sure what other description could be given than what the warning says. It just means that the same class is defined in two modules. With Apple stuff, they're often identical so it doesn't matter which copy is used.

Comment: does it still allow you to upload the file?

Comment: it seems like it worked. thank you so much for your help. I was stuck for over a week.

Comment: i have tried importing with 3 additional files and I have not recd the error message again

Comment: No worries man! Glad to know it only gave you that warning message once. Feel free to select my answer as the solution

Comment: not sure how to make your comment a solution, but woud like to do so

Comment: you can just do my answer because that is what you used, not necessarily the comment. The comment was just specifying what to do. I will edit my answer to be more specific